# Why is a resistor always connected to a capacitor in series?

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, electrical-resistance, capacitance

In my physics lecture I was told that one must always connect a resistor to a capacitor in series, because it allows it to charge quicker and the time constant becomes smaller.
Why does this happen? How does it work? Why can we not connect it in parallel with the capacitor?

Comment: Well, maybe your lecturer is wrong or you have misinterpreted what he said.  Charging of a capacitor takes infinite time if you attach a resistor in series.

Comment: The time constant is, I believe, RC for an RC circuit. So, it should actually increase if the resistor is connected.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with connecting a resistor in parallel to a capacitor. You can use Kirchhoff's loop rule to analyze what would happen if you do so.

Comment: The question is not clear. You can very well connect a resistor and a capacitor in series or in parallel. The effect will be different. It is not clear here if you are asking a physics question or an engineering question, and if the latter, in which context. It is also not clear if you refer to DC or AC. Your lecturer may very well have said that in a specific device, you need series connection or otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I'm guessing that your instructor was talking about a _theoretical_ circuit. If you connect an _ideal_ capacitor across the terminals of an _ideal_ voltage source, then the transient behavior is undefined. Add a resistor of any value greater than zero, and the math becomes well behaved.  In any _practical_ circuit, the wires _are_ resistors, and the the power supply and the capacitor both have _internal_ resistance as well.

Comment: @Krishna the charging takes infinite time but at some point(5RC s) it becomes very  close to 100% charging and it doesn't have any practical sense to say it is not fully charged because the voltage drop on the resistor is almost 0.

Comment: @JellyStrawberry Sure, but I was giving the equation in my answer. So, I thought, well, that I could be more accurate, in case the OP decides to put t=infinity, then the charge stored would be CV

Comment: @Krishna That's all he said... It was a simple circuit diagram in which he pointed out that the resistor was connected  IN series and asked why should it be so. And then added as a hint that it causes the capacitor to charge in less time

Comment: @ManuelFortin At high school senior year level physics, in a simple circuit with a battery as power source

Answer (score 1):

If the wire connecting a capacitor to a voltage source has zero resistance, the steady-state (i.e. charge $q=CV$ gets stored in the capacitor) is achieved very quickly or instantaneously.

If you connect a resistance in series, the transient period increases
[image]
If you apply Kirchoff's rule and solve a differential equation, you would obtain an expression,

$$q(t)=CV(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}})$$

You can easily notice what will happen if you add or remove a resistor.

And, there is nothing wrong in connecting a resistor and a capacitor in parallel. If the capacitor is charged and connected to a resistor, you get a voltage source (of sorts) that gets extinguished with time. (A pretty interesting thing)

Answer (score 1):

If a capacitor is connected to a power source without a series resistor, it acts briefly as a short circuit. This may blow a fuse and/or damage the power supply.